# Splitting 2 possibly negative numbers that are hyphenated

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have a Python string:

"***integer***-***integer***"

which I am trying to turn into the list

[***integer***,***integer***]

where an ***integer*** can be positive or negative and is matched by `-?[0-9]+`

I suspect the `re.split()` module is the tool for the job, however I've tried and have been unable to figure out a solution.

Here are 4 examples of input => output:

- "3-7"  => [3,7]
- "3--7"  => [3,-7]
- "-3-7"  => [-3,7]
- "-3--7" => [-3,-7]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> def f(s):
...     return list(map(int, re.split(r'(?<=\d)-', s)))
...
...
>>> f("0-23")
[0, 23]
>>> f("3--7")
[3, -7]
>>> f("-3-7")
[-3, 7]
>>> f("-3--7")
[-3, -7]
```

The pattern will match `-` only if it is preceded by digit (`\d`).

You can omit `list(..)` if you use Python 2.x.

Comment: So the (?<=\d)- means split at '-' iff it immediately precedes an integer? Does the '-' at the end effectively replace the '?' in the raw string?

Comment: @Totem, Yes. `(?<=\d)-` matches `\d` before `-`, but it does not consume the digit character.  `(?<=....)` is called positive lookbehind assertion.

Comment: @Totem, `?` is not the part of the string that should be matched but it's there to denote lookbehind assertion. There are other extension notations that starts with `(?...)`

Comment: @Totem, For more about lookaround(lookahead/lookbehind) assertion, please follow the link in the answer.